# getting a blank page instead of Hello World in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/JSX"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';


ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

When exececuting this code ,Instead of 'Hello World!', all i am getting is a blank Page.Some one please explain why?

Got a blank page instead of "hello world!"

Comment: Replace
`ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));`
with
`ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>);`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you're using React properly.  JSX need to be transpiled into Javascript for the browser to understand it.  You'll need [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) for that. Also, React needs to be in scope to be able to import it.

If you just want to try React in a simple way locally (not for production), you can use this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <!-- React+ReactDOM v18: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Babel: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- root element first: -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- now you can add your script tag... note the type: -->
    <script type="text/babel">
    
      function App() {
        return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
      }

      /* This is how to bootstrap in React version 18+ */
      const container = document.getElementById('root');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
      root.render(<App />);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, follow the installation instructions in the [official documentation](https://react.dev/learn/installation), or use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) to properly bootstrap your application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you are importing `ReactDOM`. The `render()` function is not available inside the `react-dom/client`. Changing it to import from `react-dom` would do the trick

So the file would look like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));
```